# Переопределение поставщика метаданных Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Решил исследовать работу поставщика метаданных и переопределить его. Написал такой код

```
namespace MvcTest.Models
{
    public class Info
    {
        [Display(Name = "Имя")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(4)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Возраст")]
        [Range(1, 100)]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    class MyMetaAttribute : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
    {
        protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
        {
            ModelMetadata m = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
            if (m.DisplayName == "Возраст")
                m.DisplayName = "Vozrast";
            return m;
        }
    }
}
```

Код работает нормально. Но возник вопрос. Ведь в строчке `ModelMetadata m = base.CreateMetadata...` мы получаем метаданные о модели типа `Info`, а не о конкретном свойстве (в моем случае свойстве `Age`). Тогда почему условие в этом методе нормально отрабатывает ведь у класса Info нет вообще никаких атрибутов, а они есть только у свойств внутри этого класса ? И каким тогда образом ASP доходит аж до свойств ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что, по вашему, передается в этот метод последним аргументом? :)

Нет, в этой строчке мы получаем метаданные свойства. Нет, я не знаю почему их обозвали `ModelMetadata`.